# Problema con sweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2, frontend, electron, sweetalert

Estoy utilizando la librería de sweetAlert2 en mi proyecto de electron desde hace un tiempo. Siempre funciono correctamente hasta hoy. Hoy estaba probando distintas cosas y me encuentro con que las alertas no se muestran bien, es como si fueran afectadas por lo elementos de la pagina o algo así por lo que no se posicionan bien. Como se puede ver en la foto el backdrop no ocupa toda la pantalla. Este es el codigo que estoy tratando de ejecutar.

```js
const sweetAlerts = require('../../utils/sweetAlerts');
await sweetAlerts.noSeDetectoCliente();


//En el otro archivo donde tengo todos los sweetAlerts
    async function noSeDetectoCliente() {
await Swal.fire({
  title: "No se ha detectado ese cliente",
  icon: "error",
  backdrop: true,
  showConfirmButton: true,
  allowOutsideClick: true,
  allowEscapeKey: true,
  allowEnterKey: true,
  stopKeydownPropagation: false,
  position: "center",
})
  }
```

[image]

Comment: añade esto a tu ventana principal mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools(); y podras ver las heramientas de desarrollador, el problema esta en los css, puedes decurle al script que carge los ultimos css de sweetalert y se soluciona